# Is there a way to display the currency code with string format?

Tags: c#, currency-formatting

While formatting data for excel in C#, I am using this line of code

```
myValue.Style.Numberformat.Format = "$#,##0.00"
```

It output this: `$1,234.00`

But I want to also display the currency code, like this: `$1,234 USD` or `$1,234 MXN`

Is there an option for currency code in string format?

Answer (score 0):

Dropping the `.00` part from your number format should eliminate the decimal portion:

`myValue.Style.Numberformat.Format = "$#,##0"`

As far as the units themselves (USD vs MXN) I think that's probably logic you'll need to maintain outside of the NumberFormat method call.

Comment: How we can add USD string after "myValue.Style.Numberformat.Format" this line code. If i am adding anything after "myValue.Style.Numberformat.Format" this code. Then in excel formatting not happen. Is there any way to do.?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the specific API you are using but typically there's some kind of "escape" character you can use to add arbitrary characters to a number format. For example I would guess that:

```myValue.Style.Numberformat.Format = "$#,##0 \U\S\D"````

might do it, where `\` is being used to escape the text you want to appear literally.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of the logic behind the `Style` property (ie: what is the type of `myValue`), but you can probably just put the currency code in the string format:

```
myValue.Style.Numberformat.Format = "$#,##0.00 USD";
```

Lookalike demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d0pHng).